# PECL::gnupg cannot be installed in OpenBSD 5.5

Tags: php, pecl, openbsd

I'm using OpenBSD 5.5(with vagrant box:tmatilai/openbsd-5.5).
I installed php, pear and gnupg with pkg_add command.
Also, I installed PECL::APC with pecl command.

However, when I try to install PECL::gnupg with pecl command(pecl install gnupg), install fails with following message.

```
# pecl install gnupg
downloading gnupg-1.3.3.tgz ...
Starting to download gnupg-1.3.3.tgz (19,141 bytes)
......done: 19,141 bytes
5 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootMGeDnwmXYN/gnupg-1.3.3
running: /tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.5
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.5
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.5
checking for PHP prefix... /var/www/pear
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/share/php-5.4/include -I/usr/local/share/php-5.4/include/main -I/usr/local/share/php-5.4/include/TSRM -I/usr/local/share/php-5.4/include/Zend -I/usr/local/share/php-5.4/include/ext -I/usr/local/share/php-5.4/include/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php-5.4/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/share/php-5.4/include
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for gnupg support... yes, shared
checking for gnupg files in default path... found in /usr/local/include
checking for gpgme_check_version in -lgpgme... no
configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gnupg/configure' failed
```

History of my command line is below:

```
$ vagrant init tmatilai/openbsd-5.5
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
### after login ###
$ sudo su
# pkg_add php-5.4.24 pear gnupg-1.4.16 gpgme libgpg-error autoconf-2.69p1 automake-1.14.1
# export AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.69
# export AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.14
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/php-5.4 /usr/local/bin/php
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpize-5.4 /usr/local/bin/phpize
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/php-config-5.4 /usr/local/bin/php-config
# pear upgrade pear
# pecl install apc # this is ok
# pecl install gnupg # error occurs
```

Also, I tried to manual compilation and had same error.

```
# mkdir /usr/local/src
# cd /usr/local/src
# pecl download gnupg
# tar zxf gnupg-1.3.3.tgz
# cd gnupg-1.3.3
# phpize
# ./configure # configure: error: wrong gpgme lib version or lib not found
```

gpgme might be installed.

```
# gpgme-config --version
1.3.1
# ldconfig -r | grep gpgme
        63:-lgpgme-pthread.18.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgpgme-pthread.so.18.0
        69:-lgpgme.18.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.18.0
# find / -name "*gpgme*"
/usr/local/bin/gpgme-config
/usr/local/info/gpgme.info-1
/usr/local/info/gpgme.info-2
/usr/local/info/gpgme.info
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.a
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.la
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme-pthread.so.18.0
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme.so.18.0
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme-pthread.a
/usr/local/lib/libgpgme-pthread.la
/usr/local/include/gpgme.h
/usr/local/share/aclocal/gpgme.m4
/var/db/pkg/gpgme-1.3.1p0
```

Does anyone know how to install PECL::gnupg in OpenBSD 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

In config.m4, remove "-ldl". It's not needed on FreeBSD and I suspect it's the same on OpenBSD.

Also, I had to use the following command line on FreeBSD:

```
./configure --with-gnupg=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

Someone using OpenBSD used the following

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```